# Why does the breaker trip after I replaced some outlets?

Tags: receptacle

[image]
I am installing  new outlets  in my house  each outlet has 2 black , 2 white and 2 ground wires attached.  I did the first 4 without any problems.  I got to the fifth one and the circuit breaker keeps tripping.  I tried different outlets and no outlet at all,  wire capped all the wires.  But it keeps  tripping the breaker.  What is going on?

Comment: What kind of breaker?  Is it GFI or ACFI?

Comment: What does the old outlet look like? I'm particularly interested in where the wires landed before, and if it had any "knock outs" removed between the screws.  Are you using backstab or screw terminals?

Comment: The "knock out" @Harper is referring to is a little metal tab that connects both receptacles on a duplex receptacle such that it is only necessary to energize one of them and the tab acts as a jumper.  It is common in residential to have some receptacles  controlled by a wall switch with the idea a lamp will be plugged in.  When this is done, one or both tabs on either side of the duplex receptacle are broken off to separate the two receptacles.  From what you describe, it is likely you have wired in a short circuit if any of the duplex receptacles you replaced had one or both tabs removed.

Comment: I don't know the difference between Gif or acif. I m using screw terminals.  Knockout tabs were not removed

Answer (score 3):

Double check the first 4 outlets that you rewired. You probably have the wires swapped or touching. Something like the black and white wires swapped, or a bare ground wire touching the side of the screw terminals on the side of the outlet.